# how to deploy oracle application express ( APEX ) in windows server?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

how to deploy oracle application express ( APEX ) in windows server ?
any one know about the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can install Oracle Apex on windows server in the following 2 ways:

1. If you already have a central database server. You have to install a Java based application server such as: Tomcat, Glassfish or commercial as Weblogic. Then install Oracle Rest Data Services as Apex Integrator. I recommend that you read the following article: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-installation-on-tomcat
2. As a second option you would have to install the oracle database in any of its editions for windows platforms and later Install or configure Oracle Application Express (APEX) preferable version 5 or later. you can follow the following link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-5-0-installation.

I hope I can be of your help.

Greetings.